# How to Parse with Commas in CSV file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am parsing the CSV file with Ruby and am having trouble in that the delimiter is a comma my data contains commas.

In portions of the data that contain commas the data is surrounded by "" but I am not sure how to make CSV ignore commas that are contained within Quotations.

Example CSV Data (File.csv)

```
NCB 14591  BLK 13  LOT W IRR," 84.07 FT OF 25, ALL OF 26,",TWENTY-THREE SAC HOLDING COR
```

Example Code:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach("File.csv", encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8', :quote_char => "\x00").each do |x|
  puts x[1]
end
```

> Current Output: " 84.07 FT OF 25
>
> Expected Output: 84.07 FT OF 25, ALL OF 26,

Link to the gist to view the example file and code.
https://gist.github.com/markscoin/0d6c2d346d70fd627203317c5fe3097c

Comment: is there any reason you changed your `:quote_char` to `"\x00"` instead just keeping it the default `'"'`? It works if you take out that quote_char. As it is now, you're telling the CSV library to ignore the quotation mark in favor of looking for `"\x00"` as the quote marker

Comment: I had my quote_char as "\x00" because if not than I get errors for illegal quoting when I'm parsing through around 1M records

Comment: I ended up having to clean up the CSV's to remove illegal quoting and then run Marko Tunjic's answer which worked great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The illegal quoting error is when a line has quotes, but they don't wrap the entire column, so for instance if you had a CSV that looks like:

```
NCB 14591  BLK 13  LOT W IRR," 84.07 FT OF 25, ALL OF 26,",TWENTY-THREE SAC HOLDING COR
NCB 14592  BLK 14  LOT W IRR,84.07 FT OF "25",TWENTY-FOUR SAC HOLDING COR
```

You could parse each line individually and change the quote character only for the lines that use bad quoting:

```
require 'csv'

def parse_file(file_name)
  File.foreach(file_name) do |line|
    parse_line(line) do |x|
      puts x.inspect
    end
  end
end

def parse_line(line)
  options = { encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8' }
  begin
    yield CSV.parse_line(line, options)
  rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError
    # this line is misusing quotes, change the quote character and try again
    options.merge! quote_char: "\x00"

    retry
  end
end

parse_file('./File.csv')
```

and running this gives you:

```
["NCB 14591  BLK 13  LOT W IRR", " 84.07 FT OF 25, ALL OF 26,", "TWENTY-THREE SAC HOLDING COR"]
["NCB 14592  BLK 14  LOT W IRR", "84.07 FT OF \"25\"", "TWENTY-FOUR SAC HOLDING COR"]
```

but then if you have a mix of bad quoting and good quoting in a single row this falls apart again. Ideally you just want to clean up the CSV to be valid.

Answer (score 2):

Try with force_quotes option:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach("data.csv", encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8', quote_char: '"', force_quotes: true).each do |x|
  puts x[1]
end
```

Result:

> 84.07 FT OF 25, ALL OF 26,